# Issues when converting from Europe/London time to UTC

Tags: java, android, timezone

I am trying to convert a dateTime string from `Europe/London` time to UTC.

Googling tells me that UTC should be an hour behind `Europe/London` time but when I tried to write a unit test to verify this the time calculated results in the same epoch times. I also tried from another Timezone (`Asia/Kolkata`) and that works correctly. So I am quite confused and not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the function I'm using (with a dateString of `2017-01-15 13:00:00` and both of the above mentioned timezones)

```
long getUTCTimeEpoch(final String dateString, @NonNull final String fromTimeZone) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ROOT);
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(fromTimeZone));
    try {
        Date inputTime = formatter.parse(dateString);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(fromTimeZone));
        calendar.setTime(inputTime);
        Calendar utcCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        utcCalendar.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        return utcCalendar.getTime().getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This works,

```
assertThat(getUTCTimeEpoch(timeString, "Asia/Kolkata"), is(1484465400000))
```

and this fails,

```
assertThat(getUTCTimeEpoch(timeString, "Europe/London"), is(1484481600000))
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a more modern time library like three ten abp?

Comment: this is about the only place I need to do this for now so preferably not but even if I do, I'd still like to know why the above doesn't work

Comment: Did you factor in DST (exists for London but not utc)?

Comment: Instead of `1484485200000`, what value are you getting?

Comment: sorry about that it's 1484485200000 (and I updated the right time in the post as well)

Comment: FYI: You are using troublesome poorly-designed flawed classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. For Android see the *ThreeTen-Backport* project and the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2017-01-15 13:00:00` in London is also `2017-01-15 13:00:00` in UTC, because in **January**, [London is not in Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london#tb-zone) and its local time is the same as UTC. That's why you get the millis value `1484485200000`.

UTC is one hour behind London **only** during DST, which normally occurs between March and October. If you use a date in July, for example, then there would be a 1-hour difference.

The millis value `1484481600000` is equivalent to `2017-01-15 12:00:00` (in both London and UTC). Just change the values accordingly and the test should pass.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of a conversion a lot of players are involved, a couple are:

- Local times from 2 different time zones
- Local time zone rules (BST, GMT vs. WET; CET/CEST; etc.)

Solution: Use the [java.time classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) which handles all the stuff what you need.

Looking at you, [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).